# Why is $\operatorname{Tor}(\mathbb{Z}_m,\mathbb{Z}_n) \cong \mathbb{Z}_{\operatorname{gcd}(m,n)}$?

Tags: homological-algebra

The definition of $\operatorname{Tor}$ I am using is: Let $K \to F\to A\to 0$ be a free resolution of $A$ and $B$ an abelian group, then $\operatorname{Tor}(A,B) := \ker (f \otimes 1_B)$ if $f$ is the map $f\colon F \to A$.

What is the free resolution in this case? Is it
$$\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}_m \to 0$$
where the first map is multiplication by $m$ and the second is projection?

If so, how does one proceed?

Comment: $\mathbb Z\otimes B\cong B.$ Do you know $\mathbb Z_m\otimes \mathbb Z_n?$

Comment: So $\mathbb{Z}_n \otimes \mathbb{Z}_m \cong \mathbb{Z}_{\operatorname{gcd}(m,n)}$. So the resolution tensored is $$\mathbb{Z}_n \to \mathbb{Z}_n \to \mathbb{Z}_{\operatorname{gcd}(m,n)} \to 0$$?

Comment: Or take $A=\Bbb Z_m$ [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3363461/showing-operatornametor-mathbbz-n-a-cong-ker-phi-where-phi-a-to?rq=1).

Comment: @DietrichBurde Sorry, but I'm not so comfortable with homology yet. Are they using the same defintion of Tor there?

Comment: Yes, just apply Hom to the exact sequence. But perhaps you prefer the other link above with $\ker(\phi)$, i.e., start with [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3363461/showing-operatornametor-mathbbz-n-a-cong-ker-phi-where-phi-a-to?noredirect=1&lq=1), which is completely elementary, and then look at the other post, why the kernel is just $\Bbb Z_d$, with $d=\gcd(m,n)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the free resolution $\dots\to 0\to \mathbb Z\xrightarrow{m}\mathbb Z\to\mathbb Z/m\to 0$.

Now, ignore the last term and tensor with $\mathbb Z/n$:

$$\dots\to0\to \mathbb Z\otimes\mathbb Z/n\xrightarrow{m\otimes 1_{\mathbb Z/n}}\mathbb Z\otimes\mathbb Z/n\to 0\to\cdots,$$
which is isomorphic (as an exact sequence) to

$$\dots\to0\to\mathbb Z/n\xrightarrow{m}\mathbb Z/n\to 0\to\cdots.$$
Now $\mathrm{Tor}^\mathbb Z_1(\mathbb Z/m,\mathbb Z/n)$ is the homology at the first term, which is

$$\ker(m)=\frac n{\gcd(m,n)}\mathbb Z/n\cong\mathbb Z/\gcd(m,n).$$